# Gnuplot png file without border line

Tags: object, set, border, gnuplot

I want a gnuplot png file to seamlessly blend into the background page color of a website. Setting a background rectangle for the plot with a specific rgb color spec and the same rgbfor the html page works fine.

Colored gnuplot rectangle:

`set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fc rgb "#d0d0e0" lw 0`

HTML page background color:

`<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#D0D0E0" link="#0000EE" vlink="#551A8B" alink="#FF0000">`

Now I would like to get rid of the fine black line around the plot (not the axis, the line around the border) so that it blends into the background perfectly.

I have tried `lw 0` as above or setting rectangle styles with `noborder` or `border -1` but none works. I should mention that this is on gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0.

You can see the problem on my page here:

http://drgert.dyndns.ws:8000/bmp085/bmp085.php

Thanks for helping,
Gert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

The simplest option may be to avoid making a background rectangle and instead create a transparent .png:

```
set term png transparent
set output 'foo.png'
plot x
```

That way, the image will blend into the page regardless of background color.

### Option 2

If you do want the rectangle without a border, then use `set style rectangle`:

```
set style rectangle fillstyle noborder
```

Using this option, you may get a one-pixel white/transparent border at the edge of your .png.  To get around this you can make the rectangle bigger than the screen:

```
set object 1 rectangle from scr -0.1,-0.1 to scr 1.1,1.1 behind fc rgb "#d0d0d0"
```

Note that this works only with screen coordinates; otherwise the rectangle will be clipped to fit into the plot border.